# Let $f$ be entire, if $f(z)$ is real whenever $z$ is real or $z \in \mathbb{R} + \pi i$, show $f(z+2\pi i) = f(z) $ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be entire, if $f(z)$ is real whenever $z$ is real or $z \in
>  \mathbb{R} + \pi i$, show $f(z+2\pi i) = f(z) $ for all $z \in
>  \mathbb{C}$.

I think my approach is wrong so any hints are welcomed.

So since $f$ is entire, then $f(z+2\pi i)$ is also entire (should be intuitively true?).

I tried to claim that $f(x+2\pi i) = f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and by using the identity Theorem, we can show that $f(z+2\pi i)  = f(z)$ on $\mathbb{C}$

Am I heading the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Schwarz reflection principle, $f(x-i\pi) = \overline{f(x+\pi i)} = f(x+\pi i)$ for $x\in\Bbb R$. Now, you can use your argumentation using the identity theorem.

Comment: Thanks, that was fast. Also, is there any rigourous way to show $f(z+2\pi i)$ is analytic also?

Comment: I am sorry to say that, but that's trivial. Just use the definition of "analytic".